# Get status from Samsung printer 

Tags: c#, printing

I have to develop a program in C# so that when my Printer is out of paper, a message will appear in the form indicating the problem.
I've used the WMI Tools and i have succesfully created the program. The problem is, i can see only two states. "Idle" and "Printing". Also the "WorkingOffline" works. When an "Out of Paper" error occurs, its still " Printing" and then "Idle" again.
What I have noticed is that in Windows Printers (the window that shows you whats going on) its always OK. No errors in there. The error only comes up in a program made by Samsung. Do you have any ideas?
Regards
Stelios Ioannou

Comment: what is the exact type of samsung printer? have you contacted samsung for a possible sdk?

Comment: ML 28955ND. Now I haven't. Will the give this kind of support? Monocrhome Laser Printer

Comment: without the 9? samsung ml-2855nd http://www.samsung.com/ca/consumer/office/printer-multifunction/monochrome-laser/ML-2855ND/XAA/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Samsung program communicates with the printer. Apparently the printer can send an "Out of paper" message, which the program receives and shows to you.

You either can try to talk with the Samsung program, or with the printer itself (and mimic the program's behavior).

Comment: Have any idea how can i do this?
Thanks

Comment: No. I never talked against a printer (apart from through the parallel port) so you'd have to search the www to see if there's any information on it.

Comment: Very helpful CodeCaster. Thanks. If i come up with anything i will update the post.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to fetch the status of the **SyncThru™ Web Service**

http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201012/20101208135217332/EN/User_Guide_en/english/start_here.htm